# Post Updated Value Using Eloquent

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs, laravel, eloquent

I am learning AngularJS on Laravel, and I am making a simple app. So far the app displays rows from the DB in either a completed area, or a not completed area. If a user clicks the item, it moves to the opposite area.

```
$scope.move = function(item) {
    item.has_item = !item.has_item;
};
```

The above moves the item on click, however for persistence I add:

```
$scope.move = function(item) {
    var newState = !item.completed;
    $http.post('/items', item).success(function() {
        item.completed = newState;
    });
};
```

Now, I just need a route to accept this post and insert the updated value of completed to the DB.

I've tried:

```
Route::post('items', function()
{
    $completed = Input::get('completed');
    return $completed->push();
});
```

However, I have had no luck. What do I need to do to insert the value into the DB?

Comment: `$completed` will **not** be an object, it'll be a string (or null if it doesn't exist). Hard to answer you when you're not doing any proper database calls using Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.move = function(item) {
    item.has_skill = !item.has_skill;
    $http.post('/items', item).success(function(data) {
        item = data;
    });
};

//in controller
$http.get('/items').success(function(data) {
    $scope.items = data;
});

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="move(item)">{{item.skill_name}}</li>
</ul>

Route::post('items', function() {
    $id = Input::get('id');
    $item = Skill::find($id);
    $item->has_skill = Input::get('has_skill');
    $item->save();
    return Response::json($item);
});

Route::get('items', function() {
    return Response::json(Skill::all());
});
```

http://jsbin.com/bavawiko/1/edit

Comment: I get a `500 (Internal Server Error)` still when I click an item. Is there any other code you need to see to help? Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: what is your database schema and did you defined a model ?

Comment: I don't see a completed field !

Comment: Updated to fit example: Yeah, I have a model that extends eloquent and here is my migration: `public function up()  {   Schema::create('items', function(Blueprint $table)   {    $table->increments('id');    $table->string('item_name');    $table->boolean('completed');    $table->timestamps();   });  }` in my model I have an accessor `public function getCompletedAttribute($value)  {   return (boolean) $value;  }`

Comment: I edited the answer, I assumed your model is Skill and used has_skill attribute.

Comment: I'm a little confused, I put what I have in a fiddle hopefully that helps http://jsfiddle.net/3BLwS/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50824/discussion-between-chris-and-issam-zoli)